# Trim/segment video in ffmpeg-next

Tags: rust, ffmpeg, video-processing

Sorry about dumb question, but I really struggle to find an API to trim video by start and end time in [ffmpeg-next](https://crates.io/crates/ffmpeg-next).
Can anyone point to corresponding api method or, even better, drop a small example of trimming video?
I know it's easily doable with original `ffmpeg` but I want to compile everything in single binary.

I was trying to google the problem and find clues in documentation. No luck though.